# GLM and atomic in g++ 4.8

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, glm-math

I switched from Windows to Linux a few days ago and like it alot so far. Unfortunately I have problems porting my project. In there, I'm using GLM for vector calculations and atomic together. Everything worked fine on Visual Studio.

The first problem I encounterd was that, for some reason, g++ 4.6 gave me a `undefined referece to` as soon as I was including the `atomic` header. Then I switched to g++ 4.8 and the problem was gone. But now, as soon as I'm using a atomic with a vector like that: `atomic<vec3>`, I get a new problem. This is what g++ says:

`/usr/include/c++/4.8/atomic|167|error: function ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic() [with _Tp = glm::detail::tvec3<float>]’ defaulted on its first declaration with an exception-specification that differs from the implicit declaration ‘std::atomic<glm::detail::tvec3<float> >::atomic()’|`

I have no idea how to fix that. I wanted try g++ 4.9 but I don't even know how to get that. Here is a simple code, that crashes on my machine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

atomic<vec3> b;
int main(){
    cout << "hello" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Code::Blocks as an IDE. When I'm using `clang++`, I get the same error as I got with g++ 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `tvec3<float>` isn't suitable for making a [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).
You need to check if `tvec3<float>` actually fulfills all of the constraints given from the [`TriviallyCopyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) concept:

**Requirements**

- Trivial copy constructor
- Trivial move constructor
- Trivial copy assignment operator
- Trivial move assignment operator
- Trivial destructor
- No virtual functions or virtual base classes
- All (non-static) members and base classes are TriviallyCopyable

Otherwise Use a separate [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to protect the container from concurrent access.

Comment: I also thought that, but it worked on Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah I also realized this later when I reread the question. Which VS version were you using? Could well be a bug in GCC 4.8, it's not c++11 feature complete. Trying GCC 4.9 sounds like a good idea. For clang it sounds you were missing the `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: I was using VS2012. I also thought that this might be a bug, but I cannot find gcc 4.9. I tried to set the `-std=c++11` with clang and I get a new error. Somewhere in ‘atomic_base.h‘, clang says: `/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/atomic_base.h|167|error: no template named '__atomic_base'; did you mean '__atomic0::__atomic_base'?|`

Comment: Just saw that clang is using the 4.6 libraries of c++. I try to set it to the 4.8 libraries.